# Careers bug: Can Only Open "Description" Box for "What Type of Work are You Seeking?" by Tabbing

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, help-text

*NOTE: By "description box", I mean the yellow box that appears when you are editing an option on your CV. The contents of the box explain the option that you are editing.*

Normally, all of the editable options on the "Edit CV" page on Careers have description boxes appear when you begin editing. However, this is not the case for the "What Type of Work are You Seeking?" option. I noticed that the only way to make the description box appear is by clicking Tab from the option above ("Background").

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but it contradicts the norm that is expressed by the design of the rest of the options on the page.

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you experiencing this problem in?

We've identified an issue with IE7 and its display of the help text ("description box") - a fix for this will be pushed tonight.

---

We're now forcing a `.focus()` call on the checkboxes when they're clicked - a needed workaround for [Chrome/Safari mouse focus handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html).

This fix will be pushed tonight.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 3.0.195.38. I'll check tomorrow if it's working for me.

Comment: Same problem for Chrome 4.0.249.43

Comment: Gotcha - seems Chrome/Safari don't fire focus events when checkboxes are interacted with via a mouse: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html